# understanding a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^((\w+)|(\\.))+$/
```

it is say a match of either a word character sequence or a sequence of a backslash followed by any character.
but why it can not match "form:update" with "form"

```
    var pattern = /^(\w+)|(\\.)$/;
    var s=pattern.exec("form:update"); 
    alert(s);
```

match the string "form" , 
but with outer parenthesis ,it do not.

and the two inner parenthesis is use for captrue ?  the outer one also ? 
and this example i got litte cofuse.

```
    var pattern = /^((\w+)|(\\.))+$/;
    var s=pattern.exec("form\\.update\\.whatever");
```

why s[1] = whatever, s[2] = whatever, s[3]= \.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: `^` and `$` means start and end of string, so `form` in `form:update` is not a valid match

Comment: it is not what i try to match,i am learning this, i wanna find out what is this regex means .

Comment: The expression does what you think it does; it matches a combination of word and `\\.` sequences. The matched results aren't very useful though, so I would only use it to *test*.

Comment: why a combination of word and \\. sequences ?  | is not or ? i think | is for  either   a combination of word or \ and any char follow the \ which repeat more than once .   is it the outer parenthesis make this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says

From the beginning of the string, match a sequence of words, if a backslash is encountered, match it and match one character(don't care what) that follows, then try to match another sequence of words, and loop until the end of the string.

```
var pattern = /^((\w+)|(\\.))+$/;
var s = pattern.exec("form\\.update\\.whatever");
```

The match sequence is `form` `\.` `update` `\.` `whatever`

Please note `\\` means `\` inside a javascript regex and string. `.` only means **one** "any char" in regex.

If you replace the `.` to any characters this still works, say,

```
var pattern = /^((\w+)|(\\.))+$/;
var s = pattern.exec("form\\5update\\4whatever");
```

The match sequence is `form` `\5` `update` `\4` `whatever`

> why s[1] = whatever, s[2] = whatever, s[3]= .

That's because javascript only keeps the last capture of the form `(...)+`,

the captures of the first group are `form` `\.` `update` `\.` `whatever` so you get `whatever`

the captures of the second group are `form` `update` `whatever` so you get `whatever`

the captures of the third group are `\.` `\.` so you get `\.`